# How to pass class object in HttpActionContext.response?

Tags: api

I have created one API controller and implement ActionFilterAttribute and am trying to get result as a class object.

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    ErrorInformation objError = new ErrorInformation();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            objError.ErrorMessage = "Missing Request Token";
            objError.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt16(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
            objError.ErrorType = "";
            objError.ErrorCode = "E:101";                  

            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Missing Request Token"),
            };

           // Here i want to pass my above class object 'objError' in 'actionContext.Response'
           // it is possible to pass 'objError' as a result ?**
            return;
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**After some research i have successfully resolved this issue as below.**

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    ErrorInformation objError = new ErrorInformation();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            objError.ErrorMessage = "Missing Request Token";
            objError.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt16(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
            objError.ErrorType = "";
            objError.ErrorCode = "E:101";                  

            //actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            // {
            //    Content = new StringContent("Missing Request Token"),
            //};

           // For pass class object as a response          
           var request = actionContext.Request;

           actionContext.Response = request.CreateResponse<ErrorInformation>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, objError);

           return;
        }
    }       
}
```